# using vtk with openVR

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, vtk, htc-vive, openvr

I'm trying to use VTK 7.1.1 with OpenVR on HTC Vive device. I have configured VTK using CMake 3.3.0 and built its solution using Visual Studio 2012. But when I tried to generate the solution for the example file in `VTK-7.1.1/Rendering/OpenVR` through CMake, it gave the following error:

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenVR" with any of the following names:
>
> ```
> OpenVRConfig.cmake
> openvr-config.cmake
> ```

In addition to this CMake insisted for `openvr_dir` path to be manually set but did not accept the path pointing to `openvr_master` folder having the required contents.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual to see a message complaining that `OpenVRConfig.cmake` was not found the first time you run cmake-gui after enabling OpenVR support. A new cache variable, `OPENVR_ROOT_DIR`, should appear. Point it to the directory containing the [OpenVR SDK](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr). I don't know where `openvr_dir` is coming from. You can see [here (FindOpenVR.cmake in VTK7.1.1)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/v7.1.1/CMake/FindOpenVR.cmake) how CMake uses `OPENVR_ROOT_DIR` to find libraries and include paths relative to the SDK root.

Also, what do you mean cmake "did not accept the path point to `openvr_master` folder"? Did it continue complaining that OpenVR was missing? Reset `OPENVR_ROOT_DIR` to `NOTFOUND`? Something else?

Comment: Yes,I have set OPENVR_ROOT_DIR, OPENVR_HEADERS_ROOT_DIR , OPENVR_INCLUDE_DIR, OPENVR_LIBRARY paths just after enabling OpenVR support.Also i went through the FindOpenVR.cmake as u suggested but everything seemed right there..

Comment: CMake continued complaing  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenVR.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenVR", but
  CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenVR" with any
  of the following names:
    OpenVRConfig.cmake
    openvr-config.cmake
 Add the installation prefix of "OpenVR" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenVR_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.

Comment: @anushakamath Try adding `message("Looking for library in ${_libdir}, root dirs ${_root_dirs}")` at line 67 of VTK's [FindOpenVR.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/v7.1.1/CMake/FindOpenVR.cmake#L67). Does the library directory match your architecture and contain the openvr_api shared library/dll? Does the list of root directories reported include a `headers/openvr_driver.h` file?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Drone2537!!  root dirs reported point to the folder having openvr_driver.h .But  _libdir is not set, hence it's value is not displayed in the statement you suggested.I have set OPENVR_LIBRARY pointing to openvr_api .lib after enabling OpenVR support for the first time.Can u please tell me what could have gone wrong?

Comment: The variable OPENVR_LIBRARY_TEMP in FindOpenVR.cmake holds the path pointing openvr_api.lib